# Apache2 mod_rewrite seemingly not doing anything

Tags: debian, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm having difficulty getting mod_rewrite to work in Apache2 on Debian 10. I enabled the extension with

```
a2enmod rewrite
systemctl restart apache2
```

And had no errors and can see the module in

```
apachectl -M
...
rewrite_module (shared)
...
```

Although when I add it to my vhost in the sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName default.nothing
   ServerAlias www.default.nothing
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html/00-default
   <Directory "/volume/dev/html/public_html/00-default">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^192.168.20.87$ nothing
   </Directory>
   <IfModule mpm_user_module>
      ServerEnvironment apache apache
   </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hoping that it would rewrite the url http://192.168.20.87/page.php as http://nothing/page.php in the browser tab. No matter what I put into RewriteRule nothing seems to happen. I'm sure I'm doing something

Comment: For some reason if I do it with .htaccess it works

Comment: In the vhost config you have to use a `/` as the first character of the regex. Sometimes you see `/?url` regexes that are meant to work in both a vhost or a .htaccess.

Comment: @Gerrit Not when used inside a `<Directory>` container (ie. a _directory_ context), as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteRule ^192.168.20.87$ nothing
> ```
>
> For some reason if I do it with .htaccess it works

Although this won't match the URL `http://192.168.20.87/page.php` even if you "do it with `.htaccess`", so you must be *doing something else*?

The above rule (when used in a `<Directory>` container) matches a URL of the form `http://192.168.20.87/192.168.20.87` (or `http://default.nothing/192.168.20.87` - if your hostnames resolve).

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path only, not the hostname (ie. `192.168.20.87`). So, this matches against `/page.php`, (or `page.php` - relative path/no slash prefix - when used in a *directory* context like `<Directory>` or `.htaccess`.)

So this would need to be like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ nothing
```

(Although it's unclear what you are trying to do here, what is "nothing"? If you are trying to trigger a 404 then this is not really the way to do it.)

As @Gerrit loosely mentioned in comments, when the `RewriteRule` directive is used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context (ie. not in `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` containers - a *directory* context) then the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive is root-relative, starting with a slash, because the directive is processed much earlier, before it has been mapped to the file system. eg. `^/page\.php$`.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html/00-default
> <Directory "/volume/dev/html/public_html/00-default">
> ```

I've just noticed that your `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` directives are referencing two different filesystem locations?! With the limited information in the question, this `<Directory>` container is never going to be processed.

But unless you have additional directives elsewhere (which I assume you must have) then any `.htaccess` file placed in the document root (which is where I assume you are putting it) is never going to be processed either.

Comment: I was just putting in nonsense trying to get it to fail, the question was more of trying to get mod_rewrite to do anything at all but I can only get it to do things with htaccess

Comment: @TheLovelySausage Well, the directive you posted initially will fail - it simply won't do anything as it will fail to match the request. If you do have a `.htaccess` file with any mod_rewrite directives then this will completely override the `<Directory>` container in the server config (it will do nothing). To clarify, you are restarting Apache every time you make changes to the server config?

Comment: @TheLovelySausage I've just noticed that your `DcoumentRoot` and `<Directory>` directives are referencing two different filesystem locations?! In the config you've posted this will mean the `<Directory>` container is never processed. I've updated my answer. (Where are you putting the `.htaccess` file?)